# Get user geolocation while saving object in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, geolocation, django-admin

The project have some models, as Employee, Customer, Visit, Plan and etc. The employee make visits to customers and make some notes. There is need to get user location on map, when the Visit done. During the day, there will be some visits and as a result on map it should be a road with points on made visits to customers. As you understand, here are two tasks:

1. Get user location while saving the object
2. Draw a road(direction) during day user save objects.

Comment: Have you looked at GeoDjango? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

Comment: Maybe there is any other more simple solution either GeoDjango?

Comment: You could request the users location via JS

Comment: I have found how to do it via JS. It shown the current location of user. How to save these locations and show as a road?